# Java RegEx find the first occurrence from regEx Pattern in the Input String

Tags: java, regex

I have the following java Function. What we are looking for is the first occurrence from the list **listToSearchFor**  in the **name**.

We want to get **JR**  as the output, since it appears first in the Array List.

We are getting  **SR**  (*as this is how RegEx works*)

Basically what awe are trying is if we traverse the ArrayList from Left->Right taking each element and doing a lookup in the given **input**, if there is match found stop proceeding further.

From Pattern matching we understand that, the order is from Left->Right

```
public static String findTheFirstOccurenceFromTheList() {
    String name = "CHRIS SR (A BAD BOY Parenthesis) DAVID JR CARNER";
    public static List<String> listToSearchFor = Arrays.asList(" I  ",  " JR ", " SR ", " III ", " II ", " IV ", "2ND ", "3RD ", "4TH ", "5TH ", "6TH ", "7TH ", "8TH ", "9TH ");
    String suffix = null;
    int startPos = 0;
    int endPos = 0;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(listToSearchFor.stream().map(String::valueOf).map(Pattern::quote).collect(Collectors.joining("|")));
    Matcher match = pattern.matcher(name);

    while (match.find()) {
        suffix = match.group();
        startPos = match.start();
        endPos = match.end();
        break;
    }
    return suffix;
}
```

Comment: Why is expected output `JR` when `SR` is also an expected match?

Comment: `while(bool){statements;break;}` looks to work very similar to `if(bool){statements;}`.  Why are you using a while loop as an if statement?

Comment: Are you forced to use regexes for this?  It isn't really what they're meant for, but they can be used in place of `String.contains(String)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not forced to use a regex, a simple contains loop may work

```
String findFirstTitleInList(String searchString, List<String> titles)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < titles.size(); i++) //foreach loop might not be ordered on List
        if(searchString.contains(titles.get(i)))
            return titles.get(i);

    //does not contain
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I am not restricted to regex. Just curious to see if there is a way. But for now  I am going with this option.